# How to render component in react server side with async data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-rendering

I searched a lot and didn't find any implementation to load data async in react server side before render the markup without any flux (redux) implementation. 
Here's the view (both api and views together):

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {meta: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Request.get('http://example.com/api/users').then((resp) => {
      this.setState({meta: resp.body});
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.meta.map((m, i) => {
          <p key={i}>{m.user}</p>
        })}
    );
  }
}
```

The router file (router.js):

```
export default (
    <Route component={App} path="/">
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    </Route>
);
```

And this is what I use on server (with react-router)

```
app.use((req, res) => {

    Router.match({routes: routes, location: req.url}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if(err) res.status(500).send(err.message);

        else if(redirectLocation)
            res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);

        else if(renderProps) {
                var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
                res.render("layout", {body: html});
        }
        else res.status(404).send("Page not Found");
    })
});
```

I know some basic thing that attach api calls to each router url and then resolve the `renderToString()` after that. But I don't understand how to do that with react-router.
I don't want to use any library or flux or redux implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `getComponent` prop in `react-router` to handle this situation.

```
//route.js
  function fetchAndGetComponent(location,callback){
    Request.get('http://example.com/api/users').then((resp) => {
      let meta = resp.body;
      callback(null,() => <Home meta={meta} />);
    });
  }

  <Route component={App} path="/">
        <IndexRoute getComponent={fetchAndGetComponent}/>
  </Route>
```

Comment: This is useful. Do you know how to share this data in client.

Comment: You can use the `match` function from `react-router` to match the same `routes` module with the `window.location` and call the `render` function from `react-dom` inside the callback of the `match` function in client